# Find and replace @n with a something else

Tags: regex, perl, replace, special-characters

I'm trying to replace `&00` with `@n` in a bunch of documents. Done a bit of digging, but truthfully I'm not great with perl. I tried added a few escape characters, and a few other things. How could I get the below command to work? It does not seem to like me replacing `@n` (for obvious reasons).

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/&00/@n/g;' *.wld
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@n` refers to an array, which is empty. When an empty array is interpolated, the result is the empty string. Therefore, your command would seem to delete all `&00` occurrences.

Escaping the `@` should help here:

```
perl -i -wpe's/&00/\@n/g' *.wld
```

(flags that don't take an argument can be stacked)

Comment: Wow, good job haha. Also, thank you or the quick response sir!

Comment: "flags that dont take an argument can be stacked"?

Comment: @TLP As in, `perl -p -w` -> `perl -pw`

Comment: Aha... yes, but "flags" in this case are called "switches".

Comment: Okay riddle me this. Say I have a directory structure of home/steve/frank/bill and I have files that need the above command run in each of those directories. It's rather time consuming to drop this script in each directory and run it. How would I run it from the /home directory so that it executed on all files in all subsequent directories?

Comment: @user2612011 `perl ... /home/*/*.wld` or `perl ... home/{steve,frank,bill}/*.wld`. Globs are awesome. This works for fixed depth. If you want to recurse, familiarize yourself with the `find` program.

Comment: @user2612011: `find /all /needed /directories -type f -name \*.wld | xargs perl <...>` find(1) searches for files, recursively. xargs(1) runs whatever command + arguments read from stdin.

Comment: What would that look like in its entirety using perl -pi -w -e 's/&00/\@n/g;' *.wld

Comment: @user2612011 Something like: `find /dir1 /dir2 -type f -name '*.wld' -exec perl -i -wpe 's/&00/\@n/g' {} +`

Comment: @user2612011 Or `find /dir1 /dir2 -type f -name '*.wld' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -i -wpe 's/&00/\@n/g'`